# Acronyms not being displayed

Tags: acronyms, texniccenter

I am new to LaTeX and I am using it for the first time while working on a paper and tried to include an acronym file. The code is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} % Acronyms 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
\newpage 

\section*{List of Acronyms} % 2cm distance between acronym and explanation 
\begin{acronym}[\hspace*{2cm}] 
\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep} 
\acro{FEM}{Finite Element Method} 
\acro{FFT}{Fast Fourier Transform} 
\end{acronym} 

\newpage 

\end{document}
```

It was working before but I have no idea why it is not displayed in my output file now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually it is best to post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) rather than just a smaller code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used any of the acronyms and requested that the list of acronyms only prints those that have been used by give the package the option `printonlyused`.  Either remove that option writing simply

```
\usepackage{acronym}
```

or use some of the acronyms, e.g. via `\ac{FEM}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} % Acronyms 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\begin{document}

\ac{FEM}

\section*{List of Acronyms} % 2cm distance between acronym and explanation 
\begin{acronym}[\hspace*{2cm}] 
\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep} 
\acro{FEM}{Finite Element Method} 
\acro{FFT}{Fast Fourier Transform} 
\end{acronym} 

\end{document}
```